# How to make a sync backup (aws)?

Tags: amazon-s3

Currently I have two buckets in the same region. (50TB)

I am trying to backup all the contents from one to the other through the `sync` command. But the sync command **copies** it doesn't really **backup**

However after the `sync` finished I realized that the versionIDs in the objects in the new bucket are not the same as in the old... I use the version ID for some features in my applications. So `sync` is not really an option for me.

Is there an alternative to `sync` that can backup an entire bucket with its metadata etc... intact ? namely the `version Id` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a region limitation, you can use cross-region replication to backup the bucket.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It would have been worth a try but the two buckets I have are in the same region. For CRR the buckets have to be in different regions...